# Pinning packages in RH SpaceWalk on Centos 7?

Tags: centos, package-management, spacewalk

Is there any way to pin rpm packages to versions in SpaceWalk?

We have kernels running on rare hardware, compiling the kernel is a pain and we don't want or need to do it any more often than major security. There are a number of associated libraries that fall into this category too.

Very similar to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/524043/pin-package-versions-in-rhn) but three years later and I'm using SpaceWalk on Centos rather than Satellite. Also, given the time that's passed ... surely this would have been implemented by now?

Further, this solution doesn't work for us, as we are not seeing any errata in SpaceWalk. There seem to be a couple of solutions (eg by [Steve Meier](https://cefs.steve-meier.de/) and [liedekef](https://github.com/liedekef/spacewalk_scripts)) but I am nervous to go down this route.

Comment: We ran into this issue at one point. If I recall, what we did was put the blacklist in `/etc/yum.conf`.  https://access.redhat.com/solutions/10185